# My ASP.NET Website throws an error because a referenced assembly is missing a dependent assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependencies, .net-assembly

My ASP.NET website is throwing an exception on the first request - which is when the app is first starting.

[image]

So it's saying that some Assembly has a dependency on another assembly (in this case, Json v 4.5) and that dependency is missing.

How can I figure out what is the parent Assembly is?

Comment: I'd use Fusion Log to troubleshoot this, [here](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/viewing-assembly-binding-logs-using-fuslogvw-exe/) is a short and gentle intro.